# Imported projects on Eclipse have errors

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I recently updated my ADT and now every imported project on Eclipse requires import statements. Here's a screenshot of the `OpenCV lib`.

http://s21.postimage.org/l5ou8koif/srcshot.png

**[EDIT]**
I've restarted Eclipse, the computer and every other trivial solution including "Fix Project Properties", nothing has worked so far.

Comment: What do the errors say?

Comment: @RaghavSood The errors are caused due to the lack of import statements. When I check out the source files on Notepad++ though, they're there. So, eclipse isn't recognizing the import statements for some reason.

Comment: Try pressing `ctrl-shift-o`

Comment: Yeah, I did, but there are way too many files for me to import all the statements. Why aren't the import statements recognized?

Comment: @Torcellite The imports are not missing, but their block is collapsed. You can expand it by clicking the plus sign in the left side of the editor window. If your project was working before updating the ADT, try reopening the project and/or cleaning it.

Comment: @niculare I've done that. The import statements aren't there.

Comment: according to the pictured posted, at least 4 imports are there since line numbers jump from 3 to 7. Expand that block and see which import is underlined with a red line. Maybe some needed libraries are missing from the project.

Comment: @niculare Those are imports from within the project. Imports from the android library aren't there but are actually present in the source code when viewed on a different editor.

Comment: @Torcellite This seems like a bug in the Eclipse editor. Try restarting Eclipse.

Comment: @niculare I've restarted Eclipse, the computer and tried reverting the ADT, nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded OpenCV 2.4.4 and the imported library seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

please refer this site for your reference. i think you missed to set build command
       (http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html)

Comment: It isn't just for the OpenCV lib.

Comment: @Torcellite,i understand your problem. you can even try clean and build the project. but still problem is here am rite!!!? i think some libs is missing and build path is wrongly set. can you please check it otherwise please restart and click clean all project and try again. Good luck:)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project, then Android tools->Fix project properties, then Project->clean.